# Overlay text on images SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm having issues with my SSRS report when I need to add an image to my report with text in front, I have done this before but not able to do this since and it keeps cutting my image off

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this is to set image as background image and put the text in the cell. Problem here is that image will get cropped.
It is possible only if you know precise image size so you can set cell size according to it.

It is not possible to put textbox/label over image, because report items can not overlap:
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/dd255248(v=sql.105))